# Standalone ajax script

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am working on a small javascript library that will need some ajax functionality, json, jsonp and maybe some xml.  I really like the way the jQuery ajax methods work, but don't have a need for all the other jQuery tools.  Does anyone know of a small cross browser ajax script that implements most or all of the jquery functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: my suggestion is to use Jquery , its so powerful

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to use jquery for some reasons , you can use regular javascripts xmlhttpreqeust.

see example below

```
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it has so many great features that i can't imagine writing AJAX app without it. You can use Google libraries API to save your bandwidth http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is only 26KB which is what I use.
The AJAX functionality is pretty easy and if you just need that, strip out the rest of the code.

Comment: You can't strip out the rest of the code. The Ajax bits of code in jQuery depends on the rest of the framework... it would be hard to strip out all the bits.

Comment: Fair enough, but 26KB isn't exactly large.

Comment: @coolry lot of company's are using jquery , its very powerful library ,26kb is not a big deal and its one extra http request. If you want you can optimize in various other things